# ACM-IEEE Proceedings publication notification (2015)

Tags: publications, ieee, acm

Is there a way for me to be notified automatically when a ACM or IEEE conference proceedings is published? I was unable to find such option in either of their websites. How else do researchers (professors, students, industry folks) who are interested in a particular conference, know that the Proceedings for a particular conference have been published?

TIA,
Jake Clawson

PS - I am aware of Google Scholar Alerts but I wanted to know when the entire proceedings have been published as compared to following an author or a specific paper.

Comment: I usually receive an email from the editor when the proceedings have been published

Comment: I have written for IARIA and IEEE. Usually the notification are in Google Scholar few days after the proceedings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last year, I was the publication chair for an IEEE conference, meaning that I was responsible (among other things) for working with IEEE to get the proceedings onto [Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org).  Now, more than six months since we turned in the proceedings to IEEE, and nearly as long after the conference was held, only one part of the proceedings is online.  The IEEE repeatedly promises that the rest will go up "soon," but no schedule is forthcoming.  Moreover, even as publication chair, I have do not get any sort of systematic notification about the proceedings.

Long story short: with IEEE, at least, it seems you can't. Maybe ACM is better, but I haven't worked with them on this...

Answer (score 1):

I know that you have asked specifically about IEEE/ACM, but assuming you are interested also in other CS conferences - with Springer you can get ToC of each new volume published, e.g., http://www.springer.com/series/558 for Lecture Notes in Computer Science (the major series for CS conference proceedings in Springer)